# How to force XmlSerializer to generate an empty tag when a condition is met?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XSD from another company which forces me to generate empty tags in the Xml. I've created a class based on this XSD with XSD.exe. One of the properties is a `DateTime` property. In my case I don't need this property, so I set it's value to `DateTime.MinValue`. This, offcourse, generates a tag with the min value as a value.

What I want is that while serializing a check takes place: if the value equals the min value, then generate an emptye tag, otherwise create the tag with the value.

Does someone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of converting this property to `string` instead of storing it as a `DateTime` object, you can set it to `String.Empty` instead of `DateTime.MinValue`. The serializer will then create an empty tag.

Again, as far as I know, this only works with strings.